# How to view all html content using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to find a way to save all html content from a webpage to a variable. This should work even if the webpage has frames in it. By current best solution is:

```
javascript: alert(document.body.outerHTML);
```

Just paste the code into the control in your browser where the url is placed and push enter to see the result. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cycle over all the frames and ajax-load the content.

Somethings like

```
document.getElementsByTagName('frame')[0].src
```

to get the source. But I strongly suggest you to use library to help you out. In jquery can be quite simple task. Cycle over all frames, than $.ajax request all the externals source and build it (replacing the relative  section)

But, as pointed by smeg4brains, innerHTML can be your way.

Comment: You are on the right track I believe, but I have no idea how to do this without knowing anything about the page, like how many frames it has etc. innerHTML does not include content inside frames.

Comment: But why do you need to do this in js? Anyway, you can load js library, then cycle over every frame by $('frame').each(function(i, e) { src = e.attr('src') // And then retrive all the content frame by frame })

Comment: Excellent. That is why I need. My problem is that I am horrible in JavaScript. I would therefore like to break the Stackoverflow code and ask whether I could pay you to make complete and working javascript code to do this? This means that in the end, there will be a single javascript variable containing all HTML content which is presented on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the direct answer to "how to do this":
[image]

Having this in the address bar just press Enter and you'll see the contents in alert dialog.

To see contents of frames you'll have to iterate them separately it won't be part of the HTML.

Comment: I thought I explained the same. Thanks for the lovely screenshot, though, so others can understand it.

Comment: @David - so what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
var copyOfHtml = document.documentElement.outerHTML
alert(copyOfHtml)
```

Comment: It does basically the same as we I did in my example, just using a variable.